# gradle: "make: …/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++: No such file or directory"

Tags: android, gradle, android-ndk, clang++

Running the command `gradlew build` on a Mac, I get this failure:

```
make: …/android-ndk-r16b/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
```

True enough, the named directory does exist, and it does contain `clang` (along with a number of other build tools), but no `clang++`. What gives?

Comment: Installing the ndk through **Tools > SDK Manager** seems to have fixed the problem. I'm curious as to how I downloaded a version of NKD missing clang++, so leaving this open for now in case anybody has any useful information.

Comment: Adding on: I see that `clang` and `clang++` are identical (at least for other ndk versions) so making a link would probably have fixed the problem.

Comment: At this point I'm going to call it a corrupt install and close the question.

Comment: Happened again, May 2023